# Linux Debian strange putty connection

Tags: debian, ssh, internet, putty

I have just installed Linux Debian 7.8 on my VMWARE.
Installed SSH and SSH-Server.

I'm able to connect via putty with the local IP (192.168.x.x).
When I try to connect from another computer after startup I get the 
error connection timed out. I have already a fix for this but I think
that it isn't the right one. I connect local with putty and than I can
connect via the internet. Is there a way I can solve this problem so I
can connect via the internet with putty to Linux Debian?

I have already forwarded the port 22 on my router. My IP is static.

Answer (score 2):

It's best practice to run ssh on a different port then port 22 to start with. You can change this in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` by changing the value for `Port 22`.

If you for example run ssh on port 8822, open this port on your firewall (and on the linux host if you are running a firewall there), you should be able to connect using `ssh <your_user>@<your_public_ip> -p 8822`. That is of course if your provider is not blocking any ports.

Edit:
Additionally you might want to enfore pki authentication by setting `PermitRootLogin prohibit-password` in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`. Furthermore you should use long and reasonably complex passwords/phrases. 
(As suggested by telcoM)

Comment: No matter which port you're using, I'd **strongly** recommend configuring any internet-facing `sshd` to accept key authentication only. If that is not possible, at least set `PermitRootLogin prohibit-password` in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` and use **long** and reasonably complex passwords/phrases. Even though your ssh service might be in a non-default port, eventually some automated malware will scan all the ports on your public IP address, find it and start attempting to guess passwords on it.

Comment: Totally agree on your suggestion @telcoM

Comment: I thought so :-) Feel free to add the recommendation to your answer if you want.

Comment: @telcoM done :)

Answer (score 0):

1. check port `22` if it's open (for example with nmap) from outside
2. there might be redirection issue which I experienced... when router uses port `22` for ssh configuration there is no possibility to redirect it even if it looks that you have configure it right. (Thats what I experienced on some microtik devices without any error or warn in it's log)

Try to configure your router to redirect port `222` on wan IP to port `22` on your local IP on your virtual machine.

Comment: ... And then test with `ssh -p 222 {remote-host}`